# Very last character of scanned testfile is outputting on line it is not actually on

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

Good evening all, I am working on a scanner for a compilers class. I have a testfile we must scan, print the line the token was on, what the token is and its id number. The program works correctly except for the very last character in the testfile which is a .(period). The period is actually on line 17 but my scanner is outputting it on line 18 along with the EOF token. I am trying to see if a new set of eyes can see what I am missing. All the other tokens output on their respective lines. Let me give you the scanner itself. There are several other functions in the scanner but I do not believe they are needed for this question.

```
void scanner(FILE *file) {
const int FINAL_STATE = -1, ERROR_STATE = -2;
char next_char;
static int line_count = 1;
string s = "";
int next_state, state = 0;

while(state != FINAL_STATE) {
  next_char = get_char(file);

  // deal with comments
  if(next_char == '&') {
     next_char = get_char(file);
     while(next_char != '\n') {
        next_char = get_char(file);
        if (next_char == '\n') {
            line_count++;
        }
     }
     continue;
  }

  // count lines
  if(next_char == '\n') {
     line_count++;
  }

  // deal with EOF
  if(next_char == EOF) {
     tk.lexeme = "EOF";
     tk.tk_num = eof_tk;
     tk.line_num = line_count;
     return;
  }
  next_state = table[state][c_val(next_char)];
  if(next_state == ERROR_STATE) {
     cout << "error on line [" << line_count << "]\n";
     exit(0);
  }

  // deal with final state         <------------I think my problem is here
  if(next_state == FINAL_STATE) {
     if(!isspace(next_char)) {
        ungetc(next_char, file);
     }

     if(table[state][1] == id_tk) {
        for(int t = 0; t < size(keywords); t++) {
           if(keywords[t].compare(s) == 0) {
              tk.lexeme = s;
              tk.tk_num = key_assign(t);
              tk.line_num = line_count;
              return;
           }

           else {
              tk.lexeme = s;
              tk.tk_num = id_tk;
              tk.line_num = line_count;
           }
        }

     if(tk.lexeme == "") {
        tk.lexeme = s;                                              
     }
     }

     else {
        tk.lexeme = s;                                      // string
        tk.tk_num = (token_type)table[state][1];            // type
        tk.line_num = line_count;                           // line
     }

     return;
  }

  state = next_state;

  if(!isspace(next_char)) {
     s += next_char;
  }
 }
}
```

Here is the call in main for the scanner function:

```
 while(!feof(fp)) {
        scanner(fp);
        cout << "Line: " << tk.line_num << " Token: " << tk.lexeme << " Instance: " << tk.tk_num << endl;
    }
```

If more code is need I will gladly edit this post but I did not want to overload this post with code. Last but not least is the testfile in its format:

```
& First list of all separetd by spaces to make sure nothing is missing

qwerty uiop asdfg hjkl zxcv bnm a12345 a67890 a_ a_b abcdefghij

Start Stop Then If Iff While Var Int Float Do Read Write Void Return Dummy Program

= == < > !  +  -  *  / %  =< =>

. (  ) , { } ; [ ] :

12345 67890 001 0123456789

& now some tokens without space separators

Start_ Start.Stop Start+Stop Then=If If==Iff WhileInt start stop

x=a x==a x<=1 x>=2 x,y(z){x;y:u}[1,2,3]. <-------- This period
```

Also, here is the output of the program, mind you this is only the last few lines.

```
Line: 17 Token: y Instance: 1
Line: 17 Token: : Instance: 10
Line: 17 Token: u Instance: 1
Line: 17 Token: } Instance: 22
Line: 17 Token: [ Instance: 24
Line: 17 Token: 1 Instance: 2
Line: 17 Token: , Instance: 20
Line: 17 Token: 2 Instance: 2
Line: 17 Token: , Instance: 20
Line: 17 Token: 3 Instance: 2
Line: 17 Token: ] Instance: 25
Line: 18 Token: . Instance: 17        <---------This last token should be on 17
Line: 18 Token: EOF Instance: 0
```

Thank you all for taking a looksee. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@diclophis well explained one of your problems.

(Although `get_char()` not shown, suppose it is like `getchar()`. )

1. Wrong test of EOF

   `if(next_char == EOF) {` is wrong.  `next_char` uses type `char` and EOF is type `int`.  You could read a byte that has the same 8 bit pattern as EOF and is _not an EOF and exit on the wrong byte.  Fix this by using `int next_char` and making sure `get_char()` returns like `getchar()`.

2.potential infinite loop

If `'&'` is the last byte in your file, you will not exit this loop.

```
if(next_char == '&') {
  next_char = get_char(file);
  while(next_char != '\n') {
    ...
    }
 }
```

3.Wrong `eof()` test.  This returns true if the file has not more data *after* you have tried to read beyond the last byte.

```
while(!feof(fp)) {
```

Recommend an idiomatic

```
int next_char;
while((next_char = get_char()) != EOF) {
  ...
```

Comment: The comments according to the professor are started with an `'&'` and are to end with `'\n'`. I appreciate the potential infinite loop and see where you are going with that. I am trying to stay away from reading a character in main or "priming the pump" so to speak, hence the `while(!feof(fp));`.

Comment: @Clint Not recommending reading a char in main()`.  Rather, in `main()` `int Go; do { Go = scanner(fp); printf(...); } while (Go);` and in `scanner(fp)` do the `while((next_char = get_char()) != EOF)`.

Comment: Good call! I was also thinking of "parsing" the comments in main, but then this is a small part or a larger project. We are starting on the parser and semantics pretty soon. I realize the scanner needs to be "perfect" for the other items to work. Thanks for the help! You have been "checked." Also thank you to diclophis!

Comment: Your recommendations are excellent but I do have a question. My scanner function is of the void type because of several returns. If `go = scanner(fp)` I receive a compile error of `error: void value not ignored as it ought to be`. Then of course if I change the scanner function to an int, I need to set values to all the return statements in the scanner function. Is there a way around this I am not seeing?

Comment: @Clint That is exactly what I suggest.  Effectively, anytime the result of `scanner` is a non-EOF `tk`, the `go` value is 1. Otherwise it's 0.  The `go` idea is more of a concept than a coding example.  Alternatively, the return value of `scanner` could be a `tk` instead of an `int`.  I prefer to pass data via the function, rather than though global variables.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your scanner is incrementing line number before your print out the result, since the next_char after `.` is `\n` (most text editors enter a hidden newline at the end of the file) the line_count is incremented prematurely?

I would try to remove the last `\n` from the file and see if that changes the result

Comment: How would one remove a '\n' character from a file, especially a hidden one? I used the VIM editor when creating the file and I made sure I did not add a newline in the file.

Comment: vim automatically adds the last \n, as it is common courtesy to end a textfile with a newline. You can turn this behavior off or use another text editor. However I suggest you better fix your program to be able to deal with it.